# What is the standard way to save information through a whole app session in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm making an app where the user has information that needs to last through the entire app session, across intents. Specifically, I want to do an action every time the user starts a new intent for the *first time* (per app session), but not repeat that action when they revisit the intent. My problem with using bundles to do this is that I would have to keep adding an "intentVisited" key to the bundle and would have a lot of repeat keys as the user leaves the intent again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences

Write:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

Read:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```

Remove:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.remove(getString(R.string.saved_high_score));
editor.apply();
```

Comment: Thanks, though, can you use this to edit pre-existing keys? Because I will need to do that to make this work